# Interpreter thinks 2 declarations of the same class are different

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Basically I have a project set up like so:

```
<container-folder>
        |- <folder_1>
               |- <extra_folder>
               |        |- source.py
               |
               |- main.py
```

And in `main.py` I declare a class like so:

```
class ClassOne:
    pass
```

and in another method in `main.py` I have the following code:

```
result = source_function()
if not isinstance(result, ClassOne):
    print "failed!"
```

In `source.py`, I define

```
import container-folder.folder_1.main
...
def source_function():
    return main.ClassOne()
```

However, I still get `"failed!"` printed out. When examining in the debugger, I got a bit of an odd surprise:

`result` was marked as type `container-folder.folder_1.main.ClassOne`, and `ClassOne` has the signature `main.ClassOne`. Why are these two not considered equal?

I also noted that if I changed the code to the following, using its fully-qualified class name:

```
if not isinstance(result, container-folder.folder_1.main.ClassOne):
```

I get the expected success.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same class. This is due to a quirk in that when you run a python module (ie. `python main.py`) it gets run as `__main__`. Thus you have `__main__.SomeClass` (from the root module of the program)  and `main.SomeClass` (from the module imported by `source`) , which are different classes from different modules.

To solve your problem it is best to move the class to another module and have both `main` and your `source` import `SomeClass` from this third module.

Technically you could also import `SomeClass` from `__main__`, but then you get into all sorts of tricky problems with circular dependencies.